# Sending multiple chat messages using asmack to gtalk; Out of sequence

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, google-talk, asmack

I'm tyring few things with asmack (obtained from https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack ) & google service. 
I tried to send multiple packets(in the form of chat messages) to my gtalk using service **"gmail.com"**, but i'm receiving the messages in **out of order**..

Below is the code for sending 15 packets ('chat messages') in a row

```
   String to = "testing@gmail.com"  // eg: gtalk ID


   for(int i =1;i<15;i++){
         Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat); 
         msg.setBody(i+"");
         connection.sendPacket(msg);
      }
```

Here is wat i'm getting on gtalk when runned twice..

[image: out of order chat messages]
 
I'm i doing something wrong .. can any one help me out here ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Never noticed this effect, but IIRC plain XMPP does not make any guarantees about the message order. Maybe there is an XEP for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rather than sending your msgs as packets, send them as chat msgs using the Chat class:

```
Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat(String userJID, MessageListener listener);
chat.sendMessage(string);
```

don't create a new chat everytime (maybe that's the fault in your code, u keep on creating a new Message object in every iteration), keep the 1st statement outside your for-loop

Comment: I tried not creating the Message object in every iteration, that didn't work though ( i was not getting in proper sequence/ i didn't recieve some of the packets ), You were right about using 'Chat' class and trying to send the messages using 'sendMessage', i did play around with Chat using this link http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/messaging.html found useful. I tried increasing the number of messages from 15 to 25..it fails to get in sync... so i decided to handle it more appropriately using Chat instead of blindly sending using a for loop...

Comment: @vedant1811 i am facing a problem in sending and receiving message on android device from xmpp server using asmack, Can you come over this [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68853/trying-to-learn) to help me in solving problem, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From [RFC-6120](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-10.1):

> An XMPP server MUST ensure in-order processing of the stanzas and
> other XML elements it receives over a given input stream from a
> connected client or remote server.

(read the spec for much more detail)

However, that doesn't mean either your server or your client is implemented correctly.  Start with the assumption that the server is right, and look for queuing issues in asmack.

Comment: The assumption about that server is right, it actually worked, may be i was doing it the wrong way of sending packets using the loop, when i tried to send it through a handler, i got all the messages in the proper sequence, +1 for that.

Comment: @Joe Hildebrand i am facing a problem in sending and receiving message on android device from xmpp server using asmack, Can you come over this [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68853/trying-to-learn) to help me in solving problem, Thanks